# haskell webframeworks speed, GHCi vs Compiled

Tags: haskell, yesod, ghci, servant, scotty

Today I did little benchmarking on my local machine to compare plain text speed of different Haskell web frameworks, and I noticed something strange. Almost all the frameworks that I tested, performed better when they were run from GHCi compared to compiled version. here are my results

```
+------------------------------------
|framework| GHCi rpm   | compiled rpm 
+---------+------------+-------------
|snap     | 8000       | 150
+---------+------------+-------------
|yesod    | 6000       | 2500
+---------+------------+-------------
|scotty   | 22000      | 9500
+---------+------------+-------------
|servant  | 17000      | 8500
+---------+------------+-------------
|spock    | 3300       | 2700
+---------+------------+-------------
```

I know that these numbers do not reflect on these frameworks speed, since they are not well tuned or optimized, but my question is why are these frameworks performing better when launched from GHCi. Am I doing something wrong ?

in order to build them I simply run `stack build`

Comment: Without the code it is difficult to comment. Please can you share your benchmarks and post an issue on the issue tracker?

Comment: Indeed, this is quite surprising and it would be great to have code to look at.

Comment: @MatthewPickering
Ok, I will clean up my code and upload it to github.

Comment: @bgamari
here is the link to the github repo, It would be great if you guys could take a look at it.

https://github.com/miladz68/haskell-webframework-comparison

Comment: Thanks, see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14256

Comment: @MatthewPickering
Thanks. whell it is only 2x faster not 50x faster :)

Comment: @miladzahedi In case of snap, it is `50x` faster.

Answer (score 3):

This was a recent issue found out by Harendra Kumar also in this [GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14208). You can see the relevant [ghc-dev mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2017-September/014617.html) discussion here. See this specific observation from [Harendra](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2017-September/014624.html):

> While trying to come up with a minimal example I discovered one more
>   puzzling thing. runghc is fastest, ghc is slower, ghc with
>   optimization is slowest. This is completely reverse of the expected
>   order.

If possible, I would suggest you to come up with a minimal benchmark for the same and update the ghc ticket with your repository.

Comment: I uploaded my code to github. link in the comments.